# django-allauth: how to avoid requesting friends list?

Tags: django, facebook-login, django-allauth

I have set user registration via Facebook with **django-allauth**. When I am trying to login with **Facebook**, Facebook notifies me that the app wants to get the list of my users. However, these data are not stored in my database after the login, nor are they included in my settings.py. **How can I disable requiring the list of friends?**

Django-allauth settings from settings.py:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
{
    'facebook':
       {'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'SCOPE': ['email','public_profile', 'user_friends'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'FIELDS': [
            'id',
            'email',
            'name',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'verified',
            'locale',
            'timezone',
            'link',
            'gender',
            'updated_time'],
        'EXCHANGE_TOKEN': True,
        'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: 'path.to.callable',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
        'VERSION': 'v2.4'},
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'access_type': 'online'},
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the **`user_friends`** parameter in `scope`

> `'SCOPE': ['email','public_profile', 'user_friends']`

to

> `'SCOPE': ['email','public_profile']`

so it will never get all frind-list from `facebook api`

Comment: This was so easy... Even posting, I was totally sure that I had removed this. Thanks... Could you also suggest how I should make the e-mail field required? Although it is in the scope, users still can edit this on login and do not submit their email.

Comment: umm till now i not tried it. but i will test it as soon as possible. but i think email field  may required for that. for more, we need to follow API documentation